# How to automount NTFS usb sticks on Xubuntu 12.10?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, usb, ntfs

I'm running the Xubuntu 12.10 on a Lenovo T520 laptop.

If I plug a FAT formatted usb stick, it's mounted automatically, but if I plug in a NTFS formatted one, I have to mount it manually.

How to make NTFS usb sticks to mount automatically when plugged?

My /etc/fstab in case it helps:

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid -o value -s UUID' to print the universally unique identifier
# for a device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name
# devices that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
proc            /proc           proc    nodev,noexec,nosuid 0       0
/dev/sda1       /               ext4    errors=remount-ro,user_xattr 0       1
# swap was on /dev/sda5 during installation
UUID=cd221c3e-44a8-459e-9dfb-04787f1cd0b6 none            swap    sw
```

Answer (score 0):

there is a software wich can manage all ntfs volumes for you, nice and easy.
instructions follow:

"

Add this PPA by the command:

```
**sudo apt-add-repository ppa:trebelnik-stefina/multisystem** 

Update the index files:

**sudo apt-get update**

Install the arios-automount package:

**sudo apt-get install arios-automount** "
```

Answer from url: https://askubuntu.com/questions/46588/how-to-automount-ntfs-partitions/155722#155722

Comment: Thank you, but that's not the thing I wanted: this program mounts the partitions before login, but I need to mount the usb sticks, which I insert into usb port after login.

Answer (score 0):

I think you got to add a line like this. To check on the UUID of your divice use Gpart, or:

`UUID=theidofyourthumbdrive /home/user/media[orwhereeveryouwant] fat32 rw`

To check on the UUID of your divice use Gpart, or use this in terminal:

`sudo blkid`

Hope this helps.